# Bookshelf get related data attributes is empty

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I seem to have an issue with retrieving attributes from a related model.

***Models:***

```
// DB = export of Bookshelf

// Signup model
var DB = require('../db').DB;
var UserMeta = require('./usersmeta');

var Signup = DB.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'tblSignups',
  idAttribute: 'id',
  hasTimestamps: true,
  usermeta: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(UserMeta);
  }
});

module.exports = Signup;

// Usermeta model
var DB = require('../db').DB;
var User = require('./users');

var UserMeta = DB.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'tblUsersMeta',
  idAttribute: 'id',
  hasTimestamps: true,
  user: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(User);
  }
});

module.exports = UserMeta;
```

***Admin Signup route:***

```
router.get('/signups', function(req, res, next) {
  model.SignUp.fetchAll({withRelated: ['usermeta']}).then(function(collection) {
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.toArray().length; i++){
      console.log('Signup ' + i + '\n--------------------------');
      console.log(collection.toArray()[i]);
      console.log('Related usermeta\n--------------------------');
      console.log(collection.toArray()[i].related('usermeta'));
    }
    res.render('admin/pages/signups', {title: 'signups', error: false, signups: collection.toArray()});
  }).catch(function(err) {
    res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
  });
});
```

This is what the console log shows me:

```
Signup 0
--------------------------
ModelBase {
  attributes:
   { id: 2,
     usermeta_id: 5,
     state: 'pending',
     created_at: Thu May 05 2016 17:21:13 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time),
     updated_at: Thu May 05 2016 17:21:13 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time) },
  _previousAttributes:
   { id: 2,
     usermeta_id: 5,
     state: 'pending',
     created_at: Thu May 05 2016 17:21:13 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time),
     updated_at: Thu May 05 2016 17:21:13 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time) },
  changed: {},
  relations:
   { usermeta:
      ModelBase {
        attributes: {},
        _previousAttributes: {},
        changed: {},
        relations: {},
        cid: 'c38',
        relatedData: [Object] } },
  cid: 'c35',
  id: 2 }
Related usermeta
--------------------------
ModelBase {
  attributes: {},
  _previousAttributes: {},
  changed: {},
  relations: {},
  cid: 'c38',
  relatedData:
   RelationBase {
     targetTableName: 'tblUsersMeta',
     targetIdAttribute: 'id',
     type: 'belongsTo',
     target:
      { [Function]
        NotFoundError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
        NoRowsUpdatedError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
        NoRowsDeletedError: [Function: ErrorCtor] },
     foreignKey: 'tblUsersMetum_id',
     parentId: undefined,
     parentTableName: 'tblSignups',
     parentIdAttribute: 'id',
     parentFk: undefined } }
```

So as you can see the related model attributes is empty. I saved my usermeta as follows:

```
userMeta.save().then(function(usermeta) {
        var signup = new model.SignUp({
          usermeta_id: usermeta.attributes.id
        });
        signup.save().then(function() {
          req.flash('success', 'Success!');
          res.redirect('/signup');
        }).catch(function(err) {
          res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
        });
      }).catch(function (err) {
        res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
      });
```

Within the database the usermeta's id (in the signup table) is set correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that something is wrong with your models. When you're setting up the relation between the models you use `belongsTo` in both examples - that can't be right. I don't know what is the relation between them (many-to-many? one-to-many?). If it's many-to-many you need to use `belongsToMany` and if it's one-to-many you need to set `hasMany` on the model that does not hold the foreign key in the database and `belongsTo` to the model that has the foreign key in the database.

See this http://bookshelfjs.org/#one-to-many and this http://bookshelfjs.org/#many-to-many

Hope this helps!

Comment: It was a One to One relation but indeed it should have been "hasOne". Thank you!